# How to add attribute to instance variables in a python class

Tags: python, django, class, variables, instance

To keep this simple, in my Django/Python sports pool application, each user is creating their own pool. Therefore, in the Pool class, I need to make all the class variables be instance variables so no user is changing values on another users Pool class instance.

A quick sample of code in the models.py file would be:

```
  class Pool(models.Model):
     def __init__(self, team_name):
         self.team_name = team_name
```

What if I wanted to add attributes to the team_name field such as `max_length = 100` or `unique=True`

I understand the instance variables values must be passed to the class upon instantiation, so is it that the value being passed must already be defined with those attributes? How do I handle this. Thanks!

p.s. My apologies if I screwed up the formatting of this question. I'm having challenges with inserting code. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it into the field, for example:

```
class Pool(models.Model): 
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And so on. You can refer to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/

Adding a unique constraint:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint

Comment: Thanks for responding. Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't your example above create a class variable instead of an instance variable. If each user creates a Pool instance, then changing the team name changes it for everyone. I need each user to have there own instance of Pool with their own team_name etc. Thoughts?

Comment: @Howard You can add a user field to the model. You can also add a unique constraint if you don't want two users to have the same pool name.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are saying, you don't have to pass the variables on instantiation if the fields are `blank=True` and `null=True`. You can then override the `save()` method to make sure they are there before committing to the database.

For instance in models.py:

```
class Pool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        if self.name is None or self.user is None:
            raise ValueError # or do something else or raise another error
        else:
            super(Pool, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your views.py:

```
def pools(request):
    ...
    try:
        user1_pool = Pool.objects.create()
        user1_pool.name = "My Pool Name"
        user1_pool.user = request.user
        user1_pool.save()
    except ValueError:
        # do something, send a message to user, etc.
    ...
    try:
        user2_pool = Pool.objects.create()
        user2_pool.name = "Another Pool Name"
        user2_pool.user = some_other_user
        user2_pool.save()
    except ValueError:
        # do something, send a message to user, etc.
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The  first part makes sense that the foreign key will ensure each instance of Pool belongs to a the user currently logged in when it was instantiated.

Comment: however, I don't understand the pools method in the views.py file. It seems to indicate that I will need to define a finite number of users ie user1, user2. There could be many many users each with a pool.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thanks again for your help. I'm not sure if my concerns are justified. Please allow me to expand on my example and concern.
I will have users enter my site and register. They will enter information into a form and submit which will instantiate the pool with the values from the form.
Unlimited users will do the same.
I am aware I can set up foreign keys to restrict users from only "seeing" their own pools. 
My concern is if through a form, they change values on their pool, will it change the values of all the pool instances?

Comment: I guess I'm not as clear as I thought about class variable vs instance variables.
From what I read, variables defined in a class are class variables and if they are changed, it's global.
To keep variables local to each instance, I interpreted that I need to define each variable as an instance variable, ie inside the __init__ method.
Please confirm that I am correct or straighten me out :-)  Thanks so much!